# Django Rest Framework - 'module' object has no attribute 'HStoreField'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I recently updated a project that was working with Django rest framework 2.4.2 to the newly 3.1 version but now I'm getting a:

`'module' object has no attribute 'HStoreField'`

That happens to all the endpoints including the `"/"`

Any suggestions? 
my Django version is 1.8 and python 2.7.6

Traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.dev20140910173004
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest',
'rest_framework',
'geoposition',
'rest_framework_swagger',
'PIL',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'corsheaders')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/Users/marcus/PycharmProjects/django-framework/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Users/marcus/PycharmProjects/django-framework/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  362.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/marcus/PycharmProjects/django-framework/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  398.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/marcus/PycharmProjects/django-framework/django-trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  392.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/marcus/Google Drive/Spring2015/AppContest/MyApplication/Backend/Backend/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from rest_framework import routers
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py" in <module>
  23. from rest_framework import views
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in <module>
  91. class APIView(View):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in APIView
  94.     renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in __getattr__
  206.             val = perform_import(val, attr)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in perform_import
  158.         return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in val]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in import_from_string
  170.         module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in <module>
  20. from rest_framework import exceptions, serializers, status, VERSION
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <module>
  1354.     ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[postgres_fields.HStoreField] = CharMappingField

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'HStoreField'
```

Comment: Did you also update your Django version?

Comment: I ran pip install -u Django, but I'm already on the latest version so nothing got updated.

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri How do you import `HStoreField` in your code?

Comment: @mariodev that's the deal.. I don't! As far as I know I don't have any HStoreField in my code...

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri Can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: @mariodev I edited the original post with the traceback.

Comment: DRF is supposed to be catching this error, I'd check the GitHub issues to see if it was reported and create a ticket if it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks @KevinBrown I checked on Google but nothing came out so I'm almost sure that there's not a issue open. All I did was update DRF from 2.4.2 to 3.1 and that happens. I rollback to 2.4.2 for now until I get that figured out.

Comment: I believe it was added in 3.0.4, so I'd still recommend upgrading to 3.0 first (to avoid later migration issues).

Answer (score 2):

Installing the latest release candidate of Django 1.8 should fix the issue.

You are running 1.8.dev20140910173004, which already has support for some Postgres fields, but not for `HStoreField` yet. Django REST framework only checks for the `django.contrib.postgres` and then assumes that `HStoreField` is available too. For your version of Django that is not the case.

If `pip install -u` doesn't get you the latest version, try removing and reinstalling Django.